# File and folder structure to download

Tags: magento-1.9, folder, download

I am new in Magento. Which files and folders should exclude while downloading a running Magento site to install in localhost ??

Comment: @7ochem, brentwpeterson, fschmengler, AreDubya, Wojtek Naruniec  

Your Duplicate question (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75667/how-to-move-a-magento-from-production-to-development) is not so helpful.

Answer (score 3):

When cloning stores, I often exclude,

```
/var/log
/var/session
/var/cache
/var/full_page_cache
/var/report
/var/tmp
/includes/src/
/media/catalog/product/cache
/var/backups
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much images the store has and whether they are important, I would exclude whole `/media`