# How to transfer Magento site/store view data to an existing install of Magento?

Tags: database, transfer

I'm running Magento ver 1.9.1 just to get that out there

Here's the situation:
The company I work for has 9 different magento stores running on it's live server. I was asked to create a new store-view/store. Rather than develop on a live server, I created a development server. Did a complete transfer of all magento files and database. On this development server I created and built the new site with it's new theme. Since then, we've had 3 weeks of customers/orders added to the live DB. I don't want to lose all that info, so just doing a db import from my development server is out of the question.

Here's what I've tried:

- Moved all theme related files to their proper directory on the live site.
- Imported tables cms_block, cms_page, core_config_data (edited the urls), core_store, and I know design_change table is supposed to be included, but it was empty so I didn't use that one.
- I've changed local.xml to include the new store's info
- Added symlinks in new sites folder as well as the index.php

When I navigate to the new site's url, I get this error message

```
Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Trace:
#0 /var/www/html/MagentoImage/prolinehoods/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179): Mage::throwException('Front controlle...')
#1 /var/www/html/MagentoImage/prolinehoods/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#2 /var/www/html/MagentoImage/prolinehoods/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#3 /var/www/html/MagentoImage/flagship/index.php(87): Mage::run('flagshipstorevi...', 'store')
#4 {main}
```

I've looked it up, I know there's a bunch of different things that could be causing it, I've ran through a few different debug solutions and nothing has helped.
Specifically the ones here: https://merchantprotocol.com/506/solved-front-controller-reached-100-router-match-iterations/

There's not a lot of information available on the interwebs for the situation that I'm in. I don't know how people develop for magento normally? Am I missing some tables that also need to be imported?

Would I be better off buying some magento extension that exports all customer and sales/order data for me, then just import my new version of the DB and then import the customer and sales data into that one?
It seems there's a lot more information available on importing/exporting customer information than there is for the situation I just described.

Comment: As noted in the answer by Fabian Blechschmidt's answer, you will definitely need to get xdebug up and trace through the code, starting with a breakpoint here: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(179)

For transferring over any missing attributes (product based) you can use n98-magerun to create setup scripts of given attributes. There is also this tool I created to easily create config setup scripts. https://github.com/ProxiBlue/ConfigGen

I use the above daily. I set all my needed admin settings, when developing, and export via the tool to include as part of code deploy.

Answer (score 3):

Hi shamelessApathy and welcome to MageOverflow.

For the next time, I highly recommend to implement all your changes into install/data scripts instead of writing them directly (aka configuring in the backend) into the DB, because there is no easy way to do a diff on the database. But install and data scripts create all the cms blocks, pages, products and config settings you tell them to do, so you can just deploy your newly implemented theme and a setup module which is doing all the things you want.

About setup, there are a few questions about:

- [Magento Development Setup](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10315/magento-development-setup)
- [Workflow for development using IDE and SVN](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/58123/workflow-for-development-using-ide-and-svn/58128)
- [Modern Magento 1.X Workflow and Development Tools](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/4494/217)

For your actual problem I don't have a solution. The only thing I can is: get a copy of the live system (I recommend git), make a dump of the database, delete the base_url(s) and then hook into the system with xdebug and check, why the request is not handled properly.

And yes, most likely it is, because you have forgotten to migrate something or something you made is incompatible to what already exists.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I up voted it but I don't have enough rep yet.  One way or another I will get this new site implemented with everything intact.

Comment: What might help you btw is: http://mageflow.com